# Which version of Magento to use

Tags: magento

I was wondering what version of Magento should a Web Developer work with when having to build an e-commerce site ? It involves both interactive and coding building ? Also which way would be the best to learn it well ? Does anyone know some good books,tutorials or is the user guide provided by them enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use community version,then it is better to use

```
 magento ce version 1.7.0.2
```

Why we use 1.7.0.2??

```
1.Lot of magento extension is available.

2.Upgrade version was release  available after  1 year after release of 1.7.0.2

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes#Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%201.7.0.2%20%28Jul%205,%202012%29
```

Comment: Thank you for answering ! Why is it called Community version ? Does it mean something ?

Comment: it free version of magento and open source.magento Enterprise version version and magento professional edition.

Comment: Only three versions exist currently. 1. Community Edition is free and you have to figure out how to support it yourself or find developers who can. 2. Enterprise is for those who have a large operation where paying 14-16k USD per year isn't an issue. You get extra features and hope you get some support, but in reality, you need to have a developer business partner for cost above and beyond the yearly fee paid. 3. The Professional version evaporated out of existence and 4. the Magento GO version is a hosted environment that will not be allowing you to do custom programming if you need it.